# EF Code First, Dropping tables seems very drastic

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am investigating EF Codefirst. While I like the Code/SB sync benefit, it does trouble me that the tables are dropped and data lost. In reality my dev DB could have quite a bit of test data. Is there not an alternative to this "table dropping" like the use of "Alter Table" etc.

It puts me off EF Code First.

Thanks,

Ed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently you didn't do much investigating.  Apart from the fact there are lots of ways to do code first without dropping tables (such as manually making the changes), Code First Migrations has been out for quite some time.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-automatic-migrations-walkthrough.aspx

It's not like this is any different from any other way of doing things.  You have to manually change your database when using Database first as well, and you have to drop your tables to regenerate your database in Model First.

This is not anything specific or strange about code first.  It's the way it works for every orm technology.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am learning about EF and MVC and much of my material refers to EF4.1, It seems that one should now use EF4.3. With a DB first design background my natural inclination is to do DB first EF approach, but it seems that EF Code First is the way to do it in MVC3, and yes I need to now understand "CF Migrations" to ensure I can "Upate" the DB rather than delete, so thanks for this pointer.

Comment: @EdB - The point is that this is normal for all database technologies, it shouldn't "put you off" code first because you have the same issues with anything.  And no, Code First is not "the way to do it in MVC3", it's just one of the ways to do it, and since it's new it gets a lot of attention.  Which method you use depends on your own preferences.

Comment: I think I saw it as a better way since one is managing all the validation attributes and data definition in the same class file. However as a DB designer I would prefer to start the DB design process with something like a E.Relationship design surface, but then you would have to take care not to overwrite any validation attributes as these would still be in the Model Class file. As you intimate, it may be a fact of playing with the different approaches and see what feels right for me.

Comment: @EdB - another method is to design your database as you want, then use the Entity Framework Power Tools to reverse engineer the database to Code First models.